# How to pass CSV data as a string in a web method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am trying to pass in a string representation of CSV data into a web method and then re-read into a CSV.

I do not know how to properly split the data for each row. It works if I have one line in my CSV, but if I have multiple rows it reads it all as one line.

Is there a way to convert my string back to a CSV? I know that each row should have a fixed amount of records if that helps.

**Edit:** Can CsvReader interpret new line returns like \r\n?

**Edit 2:** The web method is accessed via an API.

#### Sample CSV

> A, B, C, D
>
> E, F, G, H
>
> > This is being read by csvReader as A, B, C, D E, F, G, H as one row.

#### Web Method

```
public string Import(string csvData)
{
   //Other code

   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvData);
   MemoryStream csvMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
   StreamReader csvStreamReader = new StreamReader(csvMemoryStream);

   //Pass in the StreamReader to my other function
   return ImportData(csvStreamReader);
}
```

#### Import Function

```
public static string ImportData(StreamReader reader)
{
   using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
   {
      csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
      csvReader.Configuration.DetectColumnCountChanges = true;

      while (csvReader.Read())
      {
         //Other code
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read line by line instead of grabbing all the text.

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/path/filename.csv")
{
    string currentline;
    while( currentline = reader.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        //Do something with currentline
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I go about that? I don't have access to the original csv file currently. Should I be passing in something other than a string into web method? Can I pass that into a web method?

Comment: The question suggests you were trying to read in information from a csv file.. What are you actually trying to do then?

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear. I think at this point I'm confusing myself. Users will need to call the web method and pass in a string that I will convert into a csv to iterate over and import. I should mention that the other user will be accessing the web method via an API.

Comment: I don't know where you got that `CsvReader` class, but maybe there is something like `csvReader.Configuration.ReadSeparateRows = true`?. It would be weird if every csv file is treated as one long string. Check the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to have a direct link, but here it is: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/. I think I'll have to rethink how I am passing in that parameter. I might have to pass it in as XML. Thanks.